# How to export json template from azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

Is it possible to export the JSON definition for an existing app service in Azure?

Ie this json object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites

The app service was created using the Azure Portal UI and I want to recreate it using the Azure CLI command line.

Comment: You use `az group export  --name` to export json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `az group export --name *** >test.json` to capture a resource group as a template. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az_group_export).

But currently resource type `Microsoft.Web/sites` does not support export, please refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/15426252-fix-export-of-resource-type-microsoft-web-sites-c).

Note: If also could find the error log on Azure Portal.

[image]